# django paginator page numbers not working with if

Tags: django, pagination

I have the following template based pagination:

```
{% for ipage in transactions.paginator.page_range %}

    <li {% if ipage == page %} class="active"{%endif%}><a href="?page={{ ipage }}">{{ipage}} - {{page}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

The view page looks like this:

```
trans_list = Transaction.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(trans_list, 15) 

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        transactions = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        transactions = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        transactions = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'page':page,
        'transactions':transactions,
    }
```

`ipage` and `page` both print the page number, but the `if` doesn't display the active class when they match in the for loop.

**How can I get the if to match when the page number and the for loop index match?**

Answer (score 1):

That should do the trick.

```
{% for ipage in transactions.paginator.page_range %}
    {% ifequal ipage transactions.number %}
        <!-- Do something special for this page -->
    {% else %}
        <!-- All the other pages -->
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That did it!  ifequal, i haven't seen that one before.

Comment: @Atma - that's because it's obsolete - [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal-and-ifnotequal)

Comment: You can write {% if ipage == transactions.number %} same thing, ifequal will be dropped in next releases